# AAD Application Permission issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have added an Azure AD application and removed all *required permissions* within the azure portal:

[image]

However, the application **still has access** to the GraphAPI. If I go to the *Enterprise applications* tab, select the application and go to *permissions*, I can see the *Read directory data* permission:

[image]

**Why is the permission still there** - even I removed it? Its probably not a timing issue since I removed the permission for about an hour. I also logged in using a new browser session....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the permission is still on the service principal even though it has been removed from the application. (Enterprise Applications = Service principals, Application registrations = Applications)

Remember that the Application is only a template for Service Principals. Service principals get permissions for APIs, the app never does.

I would manually update the service principal through Graph API, or delete it and re-create it altogether. Seems like something went wrong syncing them. Normally it should sync the service principal in the same tenant, multi-tenant apps' service principals in other tenants don't sync.

EDIT: Since it is an app permission on the Microsoft Graph you have to delete the [*appRoleAssignment*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity) created for the service principal. (If it was Azure AD Graph API, it would be a member of the role *Directory Readers*)

You should be able to see these from:

> https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipals/object-id/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6

(Azure AD Graph API Explorer is not working for me right now...)

After finding it, you can just delete it by running an HTTP DELETE on

> https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipals/object-id/appRoleAssignments/assignment-object-id?api-version=1.6

If it were a delegated permission, you would have to remove the *oauth2PermissionGrant*.

You can find it via

> https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipals/object-id/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6

Comment: Thanks juunas. Are you sure that the Enterprise Applications represents the service principals? Also I thought the oauth2PermissionGrant represents the delegated permissions (not the application permissions).

Comment: Actually, the above request doesn't return any values. If I change the object-id to an application that has some permissions it shows some....

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was an application permission :)

Comment: Can you confirm that the oauth2PermissionGrant represents the delegated permissions? Im just diving into the deep of AAD and its a little bit confusing at the begin :-)

Comment: Graph API Explorer also doesn't work for me. I wrote a PowerShell module so I can test it now

Comment: oauth2PermissionGrants are always for delegated permissions yes. "Represents the OAuth 2.0 **delegated permission scopes** that have been granted to an application (represented by a service principal) as part of the user or admin consent process. "

Comment: Yes - it worked (you missed `servicePrincipals/object-id/` - I edited your answer). Now the permission is deleted and I can't see it anymore in the azure portal. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, but I am still able to invoke `https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6 ` and retrieve the users. Any clue?

Comment: Your permission was for the Microsoft Graph (the one you deleted), but that's Azure AD Graph. Does it have permissions on that as well? Because then it is probably a member of the Directory Readers role.

Comment: How can I check that? I performed a request on `servicePrincipals/ID/appRoleAssignments` and `.../oauth2PermissionGrants` and don't see any permissions anymore.

Comment: Yeah, Azure AD Graph is special... The principal is a member of the directory role and it's not there in appRoleAssignments. You can find these in `https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipals/object-id/memberOf?api-version=1.6`. It returns the groups and directory roles the principal belongs to. To delete it, this one at least should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#DeleteDirectoryRoleMember

Comment: Yes, the application got the directory reader role - who assigned it? Actually, Im not able to delete it: `Data contract version does not allow 'Delete' operations against instances of resource 
'DirectoryRole`

Comment: If you add the `Read directory data` application permission on the Azure AD Graph API, it gets added to that role. Not sure why the deletion is not working though :/